# Colloquial term for "irritable bladder"

Tags: synonyms, colloquialisms

In German, there's a term "Reizblase" which describes the bladder of someone who has to hit the bathroom every ten minutes. The dictionaries suggested "irritable bladder" as a translation which - seeing how other "Reiz-" organs are also called "irritable" - makes sense.
The thing is, the German word holds up nicely in a highly colloquial sentence. 
I'll try to emulate that in English.

> Dude, again? WTF? You really got yourself one irritable bladder right there.

I am not a native speaker but I feel like "irritable bladder" doesn't fit in with the rest of this sentence because it is a different register.

- Is there a more colloquial term?
- If not, would people say a sentence like the one in the example?

Comment: I think that in the context you're suggesting, just substituting "irritable" for something like "small" or "tiny" would be more usual.  Generally the size of the bladder would be commented on rather than it's irritability.

Comment: You're right, using 'irritable bladder' (not particularly colloquial)  with 'dude' is an incongruous mix of styles, so would most likely not be used (except by maybe physicians speaking informally). But for someone who has to 'go' a lot (not necessarily irritable), 'small bladder' is often used (this is not terribly technical, but is not really colloquial either). I can't think of a term in the register you're thinking of.

Comment: Weak bladder or, more formal,  overactive bladder:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=weak+bladder%2C+overactive+bladder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweak%20bladder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coveractive%20bladder%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Peanut bladder" is what we use in our circle (don't ask) but I'm not sure if that was an existing term or one we made up. :-)

Comment: I think simply "bladder problems" is a good as anything you can find.  (Or, for a guy, "prostate problems".)  (And, technically, the size of the bladder has little to do with how often you must go.)

Answer (score 1):

Kristina Lopez comment is correct:

I've used and heard many times in the UK

*"He/She has a bladder the size of a peanut"*. or

*"I have the bladder the size of a peanut"*.